# SOAP afas не видит поле

Tags: php, soap, php5

могли бы вы направить на решение?

Делаю soap запрос на afas

```
$client = new nusoap_client($afasGetUrl, true);

$result = $client->call('GetDataWithOptions', array('parameters' => $xml_array), '', '', false, true);
```

Вот часть xml

```
<filters>
     <filter filterid="Filter1">
         <field fieldid="DateModified" operatortype="2">2019-02-13T00:00:00</field>
        <field fieldid="enabled" operatortype="1">true</field> 
   </filter>
```

Но получаю ошибку

```
  string(55) "General message: Connector-veld 'enabled' niet gevonden"
```

Answer (score 0):

В тексте ошибки все написано: поля enabled не существует. И ты еще добавил 2 строчки фильтра в один фильтр.
Убери строчку

```
<field fieldid="enabled" operatortype="1">true</field>
```